# Where Ubuntu Gnome Looking Glass / extensions logs are stored?

Tags: gnome, log, extension, gnome-shell-extension

I've started to playing around with extensions for ubuntu gnome, gnome-shell version 3.18.5. During the development I've encountered a problem finding logs from my extension or even the one used within Looking Glass console. The information I found so far say that logs/errors should be in `~/.xsession-errors` or can be accessed with `journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell`. In my case the first file does not exist at all and the second log contains only trace about (re-)starting gnome shell `gnome-shell[1460]: GNOME Shell started at Sun Jun 19 2016 12:28:57 GMT+0200 (CEST)` and nothing more. I also know that I can use `gnome-shell -r` to output shell into current terminal, but I don't really like this solution.

The problem itself has been solved, since I managed to find the logs within GTk based Logs application that is shipped with Ubuntu Gnome. However, I would still be grateful if someone would tell me how can I access logs with a command line.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write 
`log('[EXTENSION_LOG]', <yourLoggedValue>);` 
in your code.

Open terminal and type 
`journalctl -f | grep '\[EXTENSION\_LOG\]'` 
for realtime monitoring. Then restart shell with `alt+f2 - r - enter`

When runtime reach line with your log(), you will see someting like this:

> 13:49:50 notebook gnome-session[2646]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG:
>   [EXTENSION_LOG], 123

It's a simplest logging method i've find.

Label [EXTENSION_LOG] need to separate your code logs from other gnome-session log messages, like start of extensions, or finding their locally, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to get a stack trace or find out from which file and line this log message is?